# css add text on an image

Tags: html, css, slider

i would like to know how to add text over the top each of the slider images. i have the following code html and css code

```
<div class=swipe>
<img src="static/img/cuisine/piz2.jpg">
<img src="static/img/cuisine/piz2.jpg">
<img src="static/img/cuisine/piz2.jpg">
</div>  

.swipe{
    overflow:auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

the slider works fine. but when i try to add the text as in below is does not work,

```
<div class="d_container">
<div class=swipe>
  <div>
      <img src="static/img/cuisine/piz2.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
      <div class="d_bottom-left">Bottom Left</div>
      <div class="d_top-left">Top Left</div>
      <div class="d_top-right">Top Right</div>
      <div class="d_bottom-right">Bottom Right</div>
      <div class="d_centered">Centered</div>
      <img src="static/img/cuisine/piz2.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
      <div class="d_bottom-left">1Bottom Left</div>
      <div class="d_top-left">1Top Left</div>
      <div class="d_top-right">1Top Right</div>
      <div class="d_bottom-right">1Bottom Right</div>
      <div class="d_centered">1Centered</div>
  </div>  
 </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Where does your text get positioned? If you have it aligned correctly, it's likely a `z-index` issue.

Comment: The code you have provided does not allow us to reproduce the issue at all. See: https://jsfiddle.net/Lhq8m1gb/ here are some guidelines on what to provide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You have to position your text in your CSS, you also need to add z-index values as mentions by @Obsidian Age.

```
.d_bottom-left{
     position: relative;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     z-index: 999;
 }
```

sources :

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: CodeKracken appreciate your response. Still did not work for me. Getting someone else to do it now. thanks